# Creating an if-statement in mathematical modelling

Tags: conditional-statements, modeling

Im trying to make a mathematical model for flexible job shop scheduling. In this model, operations can be divided into certain sub-groups, and relations between operations in the subgroup, and those outside of it can be defined. If an operation belongs in subgroup *y* the operations y value would be 1, and otherwise it will be set to 0. Whenever I create a relation between two operations i can the use a sufficiently large number L so that

> T1+((1-y1)*L)<= T2+((1-y2)*L)

This ensures that the T value of operation 1 is smaller than that of operation 2 if operation 1 belongs in subgroup y, and operation 2 doesn't.

While this method works as a improvised if-statement, it seems incredibly clunky, does anyone know of a better way to achieve the same effect?